# Get datatypes of result fields in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to make my PHP scripts a little safer and in future always save variables with the correct data type. Especially to avoid errors when comparing with != and ==.

This is not a problem with generated variables by script. But what is the best way to deal with content from the mySQL database? **Is it possible to display the data type of the fields for the queries?**

It seems to me that the only way to get this is to manually assign the correct data type in the script with inval() or strval() when fetching the result. What do you think?

I would like to avoid queries with "SHOW COLUMNS" or "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS" as much as possible, because I have several hundred tables and the queries are often very specifically composed.

Comment: Shouldn't your code know what type each value should be? Do you really need to handle types dynamically?

Comment: Please provide a scenario where you need to get the specific datatype for your code to work, or where it may return error (the one you want to avoid).

Comment: I've written generic report-formatting programs to accept a variety of queries and format the results in a usable way without stick-building the displayed columns. That's what this is for.

Comment: See this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php if you like mysqli.  And this https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php if you like PDO. They retrieve all the available column metadata, like data type, column length, column name. But **do not blindly trust this metadata.** Check it to make sure it's well-formed, and be rude if it isn't.

Comment: I noticed the following: 
 if( 'red' == 0 )  => gets true!!!!
 if( 'red' === 0 )  => gets false

Therefore, I would like to consider the data type cleanly everywhere and this starts with the queries from the database.

Comment: Thanks, O. Jones, your answer solves my problem.